# Python three integers to hex string

Tags: python

I'm using python to control a mouse, for that I need to convert 3 integers to a hex value like `b'\x00\x64\x64'`

#### What I've tried

```
return b'\x00' + hex(x) + hex(y)
```

But my IDE doesn't like this syntax, am I missing anything?

Comment: Um, did you check what `hex(x)` actually returns?

Comment: It does return values such as 0x102
0x200
0xf4
0x200
0x200, is my syntax correct?

Comment: Not exactly. Those are *strings*! For example, `hex(42) == '0x2a'` is a string of length 4.

Comment: I guess one way to do this is `chr(42).encode('utf-8')`... though perhaps there's a more efficient way.

Comment: @Notflip, `b"\x00\x64\x64"` is invalid bytesting. Could you explain what are you planning to do and why you need this?

Comment: I meant not invalid, but useless

Comment: It's to control a HID device (a mouse) this is the data I'm sending to the HID emulator on the device

Comment: @OlvinRoght It can't be invalid... see here: https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#bytes

Comment: Could the fromHex() function be of help? https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#bytes.fromhex

Comment: @MateenUlhaq, read next comment I've posted ;)

Comment: @Notflip, HID device can't expect string of byte values in hex, it's impossible. Check docs again.

Comment: I saw it like that in most tutorials, what data does it expect then @OlvinRoght?

Comment: @Notflip, I don't know what device you're working with, but normally it expect array of bytes (`list`, `bytes`, `bytearray` in python) or dword value (`int`).

Comment: Isn't that string an array of bytes? What's the difference?

Comment: @Notflip, bytestring you're asking for is next list(array) - `[92, 120, 48, 48, 92, 120, 54, 52, 92, 120, 54, 52]`, cause it representing char codes  of all useless text in this bytestring. I'm sure that you need next - `[0, 100, 100]`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The simplest is probably to use the `struct` module:

```
import struct

def f(x, y):
    return struct.pack('bbb', 0, x, y)
```

Another way to do it without `struct`:

```
def byte_to_bytestr(x):
    return x.to_bytes(1, byteorder='big')

def f(x, y):
    return b''.join(map(byte_to_bytestr, [0, x, y]))
```

Answer (score 0):

```
x = 100
y = 100

print(bytes("\x00\{}\{}".format(hex(x), hex(y)), 'utf-8'))
```

That should do the trick

Comment: `print(bytes("".join("\\x{:02x}".format(i) for i in (0, 100, 100)), "utf-8")`